# How to get the value of selected spinner item in string

Tags: java, android, string, android-spinner

I want to get the selected `Spinner` value in a string. I have used "**Material better spinner Library**"  for the `Spinner`:

```
import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner;
```

Now I created this string array:

```
 String[] List_Rooms = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"};
```

and I used spinners like this:

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter_rooms = 
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
      List_Rooms);         
MaterialBetterSpinner materialDesignSpinner = 
        (MaterialBetterSpinner)findViewById(R.id.main_spn_no_of_room); 
materialDesignSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter_rooms);
```

Now I want to get selected value of the Spinner in a string. I need your help with this.

Comment: try this  String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: I suggest that you read the documentation for the library you are using.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: i tried this, String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();  but it shows error, cant resolve symbol mySpinner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String text = mySpinner.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

MaterialBetterSpinner class extends android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView so I think `materialDesignSpinner.getText()` works.